# How do I do something like this some_function({1,1,1,1})?

Tags: c++, arrays

Lets say I have a function with prototype like this: `int func(int * a)`, and it accepts an array as an argument.

How do I do this without the compiler showing errors everywhere: func({1,1,1,1})

Comment: Please add your complete code.  int funct(int * a) doesn't accept an array as an arguement, it accepts an int pointer.

Comment: "How do I do that without the compiler showing errors" is a very curious way of asking for "how to write correct code"...

Comment: @KerrekSB I would agree with him. What he tries to write makes good sense. The computer should adapt to the humans, not the opposite ;-)

Comment: @Offirmo: Unfortunately, this is tagged "C++" and not "Apple".

Comment: @Offirmo: Unfortunately we do not live in a magical utopian fantasy land where computers are not incredibly, _incredibly_ complicated, and where we don't need written standards to interface with them semi-reliably.

Comment: (More importantly, it's evidence of a particular type of approach to programming. A wrong one.)

Comment: @user1148237: Don't listen to the zealots! Your question is perfectly legitimate. And it has a simple answer, too -- see my solution below.

Comment: Nobody said otherwise, @TonyK. And your answer is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you need is an `(int[])` cast:

```
#include <iostream>

static void f (int* a) {
  while (*a) std::cout << *a++ << "\n" ;
  }

int main() {
  f ((int[]){1,2,3,4,0}) ;
  }
```

This code outputs

```
1
2
3
4
```

It works in C too -- see [this ideone link](http://ideone.com/GOEwk).

**Updated to add:** I posted [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8861266/428857) about the legality of this construct, and [Mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8861313/428857) is worth reading if you're interested in that kind of thing. Briefly, it seems that it is valid only in C99, but that some compilers allow it as an extension in all C/C++ variants.

Comment: First, you need a sentinal, which could be a legitimate value in the sequence---how would you pass `{ 1, 0, 2, 3 }`?  And the syntax is not legal C, nor C++ pre C++11.

Comment: @James -- your first objection is just silly: my program was simply a small example. As for your second objection, the OP specifically asked how to get the compiler to accept the construct. My code meets that criterion, at least under gcc.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Is this even legal C++11? I didn't think that compound literals were ever part of C++...

Comment: It makes sense. It works. Why wouldn't it be legal? Give me chapter and verse, please!

Comment: @TonyK: Since you're the one who came up with the example, you're the one who needs to provide "chapter and verse" as to why it *is* legal.

Comment: Hard to provide a citation that doesn't exist.

Comment: @KerrekSB C++ doesn't accept compound literals, as defined in C99, but it does have an extended initialization syntax which achieves more or less the same ends.  I don't think that `(int[]){1, 2, 3, 4)` is legal, but if you have a `typedef int int4[4]`, `int4{1, 2, 3, 4}` would be (I think---I've not any real experience with C++11).

Comment: @TonyK First, it doesn't work with the compilers I use.  Second, the reason it's illegal is because there is no production in C++ syntax which would generate it.

Comment: @JamesKanze It is legal C99. Stop whining and downvoting.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
int func(int * a);

void somewhere_else()
{
    int arr[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    func(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use raw arrays, and certainly don't pass pointers to them into functions. Ew! We're not in 1975 any more.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void func(std::vector<int> const& v) {
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      std::cout << v[i] << " ";
}

int main() {
   func({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
}

// Output: "1 2 3 4 "
```

This requires a compiler that is compliant with certain features of C++11. Namely initializer lists.

Comment: Meh, every tool has its advantages and disadvantages. Saying "don't use raw arrays', 'don't pass pointers' etc is waaaay too close-minded and childish. And yes, initializer lists constructors are awesome, but C++11 has only been around for months, please... its teaching someone how to use the GPS when they ask you how to drive a car!

Comment: @BrianNeal: Yes, that is correct. It is a code sample written in 2012, which is the current year.

Comment: @Giovanni: This is the answer to the question. It's out of my hands that it involves C++11. And, really, there is _no_ reason to use raw arrays when we have tools like `{std,boost}::array` -- it's reasonable to generalise there, because it's unreasonable (as advice to a mid-level developer, anyway) to ignore the advantages. Calling me "childish" won't change that.

Comment: Well I just thought you ought to mention that because not all of us can use C++11 features yet. Glad you added that to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
int func(std::initializer_list<int> a) {
  // do something with a here
}
```

Or you can write a wrapper that uses `std::initializer_list` (if for some reason you cannot change the original function):

```
int func_wrapper(std::initializer_list<int> a) {
  std::vector<int> b = a;
  func(b.data());
}
```

Comment: Which requires C++11 support for initializer lists.

Comment: The only reason not to use C++11 is having no decent compiler available for the target platform. But you are right, yes.

Comment: But there are a *lot* of target platforms that don't have the proper support. There are a lot of compilers that people use, whether it is because they have to or simply want to, that do not have that level of C++11 support. It's common courtesy to at least mention that a solution you offer requires features that the user may not have. In a few years, maybe we can assume C++11 support universally, but until then no.

Comment: There are enough other reasons like having to support multiple platforms, coding requirements, legacy source bases, ...

Answer (score 1):

one way to do that would be

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>


  void abc (int *a,int z)
  {
   int m= z/sizeof(*a);    
   for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
      {
        std::cout<<"values " <<*a<<"\n";
        a++;
      }     
  }
 int main()
 {
   int ar[]={11,12,13,14,15,1166,17};
   std::cout << sizeof(ar)<<"size\n";
   abc(ar,sizeof(ar));   
   getchar();
 }
```

here in this case you dont need to worry about size and all. In case of 
int ar[3]={1,2,3} that will give junk values if you try and search for NULL as 
the third place is occupied by element 3

Comment: Have you tried it with various arrays of different sizes?  Or on a 64 bit machine?  `sizeof(a) in your function is the size of the pointer; you cheated by passing an array which just happened to have the same number of elements as there are bytes in a pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze ya thats a mistake on my part.

Comment: @JamesKanze posted the new fix and tested it with more than 4 elements which is the size of integer pointer.. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Now it only works because the size of a pointer is the same as the size of an `int`. Try this on a 64-bit platform and it won't work anymore. You should divide by the `sizeof(*a)` (i.e. size of *an element*), not `sizeof(a)` (i.e. size of *a pointer*). Or simply pass the number of elements directly.