# Is this legal C/C++? `int* p = (int[]) {1,2,3} ;`

Tags: c++, c, arrays, standards, literals

[This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8855343/428857) generated some comments claiming that the following construct is not legal C/C++:

```
void f (int* a) ;
f ((int[]){1,2,3,4,0}) ;
```

(see [this ideone link](http://ideone.com/GOEwk) for a full program). But we weren't able to resolve the issue. Can anybody shed any light on this? What do the various standards have to say?

Comment: I think @Nicol Bolas is right, who commented on your post. Not everything that works, is valid. That's actually really often the case. I would say the snippet in your comment results in 'undefined behaviour'. So if you want to prove him it's legal, you have to grab out/search within the c/c++/c++11 standard.

Comment: @Michael: I don't want to prove it's legal, I just want to know whether it's legal or not. The comments to my post (including my comments) are just opinions.

Comment: Why is it undefined behaviour?

Comment: FWIW, your ideone link is compiling the code as C. And compiling this with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++98` yields "warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals".

Comment: @R: ideone compiles all four C/C++ variants (C, C++, C++0x, C99 strict) without warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's valid C99 as far as I can tell - that's passing a compound literal.

The C99 standard has this as an example (§6.5.2.5/9):

> EXAMPLE 1 The file scope definition

```
int *p = (int []){2, 4};
```

> initializes p to point to the first element of an array of two ints, the first having the value two and the second, four. The expressions in this compound literal are required to be constant. The unnamed object has static storage duration.

Note that the `(int [])` thing is not a cast here.

This is not a valid C++ construct though, compound literals are not part of the C++ standard (C++11 included). Some compilers allow it as an extension. (GCC does, pass `-Wall -pedantic` to get a diagnostics about it. IBM xlC [allows it as an extension too](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc02compound_literals.htm).)

Comment: Note that the array object has static storage duration only if it's at file scope, as in the example.  If it appears inside a function definition, then it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block (i.e., the object and any pointer to it become invalid when execution reaches the enclosing `}`).  This is unlike string literals, which always have static storage duration.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to cover everything.

Comment: What storage duration would `char *p = (char[]) { 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 0 }` have?

Comment: @drhirsch: automatic if inside a function, static if at global scope.

Answer (score 1):

The expression passed as argument to the function is an example of a *compound literal*. These are legal in C99, but not in C++98.

See for example section 6.4.4 "Constants" and 6.8 "Statements and blocks" in [N897 "A draft rationale for the C99 standard."](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n897.pdf) See also [this section](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) of GCC documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think it is valid according to C++11. Section 5.2:

```
postfix-expression:
    ...
    typename-specifier ( expression-listopt )
    simple-type-specifier braced-init-list
    typename-specifier braced-init-list
    ...
expression-list:
    initializer-list
```

**EDIT:**
After some more reading I came to conclusion it's actually **invalid**, because you cannot use postfix expression like that. There should be some primary expression.

Comment: You could quote. And I don't see anything there that makes this valid.

Comment: The snippet you posted doesn't match the question. If you're interested, this kind of cast syntax is in §5.4 not §5.2. You should also read through the allowed conversions and you will find out that you're not allowed to cast into an array type.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: Now I'm confused. I'd think `typename-specifier braced-init-list` could write eq. as `sometype {1, 2, 3, 4}`, but gcc doesn't allow me to do this. Is this supposed for structs only, or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Yes, that syntax, while not the one in question, is allowed. Either you have a version of GCC prior to 4.6, or you're not compiling with `-std=c++0x`, or you have something else wrong in the code (did you make sure `sometype` has an appropriate constructor?)

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. It allowed me to use this syntax with structs only (ie. sometype was a struct). I didn't try class with a custom constructor, but I guess it would be the same.

Comment: Oh, yes, it only works for user-defined types. It doesn't work for arrays.

Comment: Ahh, I feel so stupid now! The array is not a simple type, am I right?